# Boolean subset with named index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, boolean

I'm trying to use a boolean array to subset a data frame. This works:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        (0, 0, 1),
        (0, 1, 2),
        (0, 3, 20),
        (1, 0, 2),
        (1, 1, 1),
        (1, 2, 30),
    ],
    columns = ['s', 'j', 'q']
)

df[df['j'] == 0]
df.loc[df['j'] == 0]
```

However, the following fail:

```
df.set_index('s')[df['j'] == 0]
df.set_index('s').loc[df['j'] == 0]
```

I get every instance wehere `s` equals 0, not `j`. I've resorted to query (my condition is more complicated than literally `j == 0`, or I would use it directly):

```
df['sub'] = (df['j'] == 0)
df.query('sub')
```

Is there a way to do this without creating a temporary variable? Many thanks! Python 3.7 and pandas 0.23.4

**EDIT**

The issue with what I was doing was that the boolean series and the data frame have different indexes. The answer below details several ways to work around it, but I was for either of these two methods:

```
df.set_index('s')[(df['j'] == 0).values]
```

or

```
df.set_index('s', inplace = True)
df[df['j'] == 0]
```

Comment: What's the *purpose* of `df.set_index('s')`? It seems your current solution doesn't use `s` as the index, nor does it require it.

Comment: @jpp As most people might guess, my code does not end after I sub-set the data for no apparent reason...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't re-set the index between boolean operations. Your boolean series is based on the original index to place the true and false values, you can't then re-use that series on a dataframe with a *different* index, as the indices then map to different rows through that new index.

If you must create a dataframe with a different index, create your boolean array *after* doing so, or on another dataframe with the same index. So this works:

```
df.set_index('s')[df.set_index('s')['j'] == 0]
df.set_index('s').loc[df.set_index('s')['j'] == 0]
```

as does

```
df_indexed_on_s = df.set_index('s')
df_indexed_on_s[df_indexed_on_s['j'] == 0]
df_indexed_on_s.loc[df_indexed_on_s['j'] == 0]
```

If you must do this inline, perhaps you want to use a callable index; a function passed in to the `[...]` indexing operation is expected to return a boolean series, so you can use that too:

```
df.set_index('s')[lambda sdf: sdf['j'] == 0]
df.set_index('s').loc[lambda sdf: sdf['j'] == 0]
```

or you could use [`DataFrame.query()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) to have Pandas evaluate a the query expressed as in a string against the dataframe for you:

```
df.set_index('s').query('j == 0')
```

Under the hood, the index attached to `df.set_index('s')` is iterated over, and the values in that index checked against that of the `df['j'] == 0` series to see what rows should be selected. The latter series still uses the original index (a `RangeIndex` with numbers 0 - 6), so mapping the numbers 0 - 6 to `True` and `False` values, while `s` only has a `Int64Index` index with the values `0` and `1`. For the rows where the `s` index has `0`, the `(df['j'] == 0)[0]` outcome is `True`, so those rows are selected, while for `1` the outcome is `False`.

A boolean index for `df_indexed_on_s[df_indexed_on_s['j'] == 0]` needs a bit more work as there the index is the same `s`-based Int64Index`, and`0` maps to 3 separate boolean results, so Pandas knows to use more than the index to select matching rows.

Comment: Those also support callables: `df.set_index('s')[lambda df: df['j'] == 0]`

Comment: @ayhan: at which point the current dataframe is passed in for the lambda argument, yes.

Comment: I'd also point out the version `df.set_index('s').query('j == 0')`, which will work for many simple indexing needs. It doesn't require construction of an explicit series (uses top-level `pd.eval`).

Comment: How about aligning with the underlying `ndarray` since `.set_index` wont modify the ordering? `df.set_index('s')[(df.j==0).values]`?

Comment: @ALollz: even more possibilities, yes passing in a numpy boolean array is another option. I think we should stop listing ever more options though.

Comment: Thanks! The first paragraph explains my mistake very well.